# Text read from SD Card, not showing in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-file

I feel like I'm very close to a solution... I'm getting no errors or crashes, but my text file from my SD card is simply not showing.

Intention: I am trying to read ALL files from a particular directory in my Documents directory on my SD card, then once each file is read, it should be loaded into my `ListView` via my adapter. I have a model set up (`PoemListItem.java`), that should retrieve the title of the file, and the contents of the file, both in `Strings`. I know that it reaches the file in the directory, because when I take away the `for loop` that adds default text (in case there are not many files in the directory) into the `ArrayList<>`, then the number of lines in the list are exactly equal to the number of files in the directory. So that part works at least. Only problem is there is nothing showing. Why?

Thanks for your help!

Here you can see that one list item displays (since there is one file in the SD card directory of choice), but that title and text are hint code from the xml, not the actual file title and contents. I assume the hint text is overridden when you import file contents instead? It doesn't seem to be here... The actual title and text that are supposed to be there instead is simply: File name and Test 2... instead of Title and Quote or poem, here.

[image]

**TextTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class TextTab extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<PoemListItem> poems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListViewPoemAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    String[] allSDCardFiles = null;
    StringBuilder text;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_tab, container, false);
        adapter = new ListViewPoemAdapter(getActivity(), poems);
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // read contents of SD card
        loadSDCard();

        // add the default icon/lines remaining to ArrayList, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - allSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
            PoemListItem sampleItem = new PoemListItem(" ", " ");
            adapter.add(sampleItem);
            i++;
        }

        setupListViewListener();

        return v;

    }

    private void loadSDCard(){
        // gets directory CuteWords rom sd card
        File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cuteWordsDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CuteWords");
        // lists all files in CuteWords, loads in Files[] array
        File[] files = cuteWordsDir.listFiles();

        for (File singleFile : files) {
            //Read text from file, put each line into StringBuilder
            text = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(singleFile));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                    // add file name and text in file to adapter, to display in ListView
                    PoemListItem wordsFromFile = new PoemListItem(singleFile.getName(),
                                                                        text.toString());
                    adapter.add(wordsFromFile);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // get number of files in CuteWords directory
        allSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];
    }

    // so you can edit any of the list items
    private void setupListViewListener() {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                        View item, int pos, long id){

                // code to edit then save typed text
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                poems.remove(pos);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                writeItems();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is my model:
**PoemListItem.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 3/12/15.
 */
public class PoemListItem {

    private String title;
    private String poem;

    public PoemListItem(){}

    public PoemListItem(String t, String p){
        this.title = t;
        this.poem = p;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPoem(){
        return poem;
    }

    public void setPoem(String poem){
        this.poem = poem;
    }

}
```

You probably don't need to see the adapter, but just in case:

**ListViewPoemAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class ListViewPoemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PoemListItem> {

    private Context context;
    private EditText poemText;
    private EditText poemTitle;
    private ImageView poemPlaceholder;


    public ListViewPoemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PoemListItem> poems) {
        super(context, 0, poems);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        PoemListItem poemListItem = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.text_listview_row, parent, false);
        }

        poemTitle = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_text_title);
        poemText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        poemPlaceholder = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_placeholder_poem);

        poemPlaceholder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_poem_placeholder);
        poemPlaceholder.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        poemPlaceholder.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150));



//        poemTitle.setText(poemListItem.getTitle());
//        poemText.setText(poemListItem.getPoem());

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after line adapter.add(wordsFromFile)

Comment: Thanks Ram, I tried to add that but still nothing shows.

Comment: use poems.add(wordsFromFile) instead of adapter.add(wordsFromFile) and after that use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thanks, I did think to try that too, but still, nothing is showing. I did `Log` statements, to make sure each part has a value, like `files` and `wordsFromFile`, and they do (although they're hash codes).. so I know things have a value. But what I don't get is why will the `for loop` print out stuff, but not the info from the `File`? I am using the same method to add them to the view, but still it's not working. Maybe the `readline()` code is wrong and it's reading nothing? Not sure.

Comment: what is this .. for (int i = 0; i < (24 - allSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
            PoemListItem sampleItem = new PoemListItem(" ", " ");
            adapter.add(sampleItem);
            i++;
        }

Comment: That code adds "empty" placeholders to the `ArrayList<>` only if there are no files to load. I tried to comment out that code, to see if it was messing things up, but it was not. Instead of loading a bunch of placeholder lines, it just loaded 2 list items (since there were 2 files) and they were still blank. So I don't really even need that code, I just want viewers to see a full list, even if they have few files to draw from. At some point, I'll enable a click listener to those items, so people can add info on the fly, instead of only from file.

Comment: @Ram, wow, totally got it! I had some missing lines in my adapter. I posted the solution in an answer, below. Good to know the File I/O stuff was right!

Answer (score 0):

Your arraylist is empty. 
Add "wordsFromFile" in arraylist instead of adapter.

Comment: Thanks DM, although I always thought that is how you add items to an `ArrayList`, through the adapter. I cannot think of how to add items otherwise. Because when I add anything in my `sampleItem` variable code (like if I fill the empty Strings with something), then it does add them to the view. So I know that `adapter.add(item to add)` should work. Unless you can think of an alternative in code, I can't think of how it would look.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake! My adapter code that was referencing my model (to hook up my views) was not complete. When you create a model to use for your custom `ListView` (that has a separate `xml` file for the list row), then you must include in your model what goes into your list items. In my case, I had two `EditText` items representing the title and the poem text itself. So my model was missing these lines:

```
PoemListItem poemListItem = getItem(position);

poemTitle.setText(poemListItem.getTitle());
poemText.setText(poemListItem.getPoem());
```

Below, you can see them in context. As soon as I uncommented them, I found my List populated with the title and text body in the files from the SD Card. The only reason I had them commented out, was so my hint text from my `xml` `EditText`s would show. Now the hint text does not show on the placeholder lines of the list, but that's a compromise I can live with. So most of my code was right, I just had a few missing lines in my adapter.

**ListViewPoemAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class ListViewPoemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PoemListItem> {

    private Context context;
    private EditText poemText;
    private EditText poemTitle;
    private ImageView poemPlaceholder;


    public ListViewPoemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PoemListItem> poems) {
        super(context, 0, poems);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        PoemListItem poemListItem = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.text_listview_row, parent, false);
        }

        poemTitle = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_text_title);
        poemText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        poemPlaceholder = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_placeholder_poem);

        poemPlaceholder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_poem_placeholder);
        poemPlaceholder.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        poemPlaceholder.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150));

        poemTitle.setText(poemListItem.getTitle());
        poemText.setText(poemListItem.getPoem());

        return convertView;
    }
```